# With Python Kubernetes client, how to replicate `kubectl create -f` generally?

Tags: python, kubernetes

My Bash script using `kubectl create/apply -f ...` to deploy lots of Kubernetes resources has grown too large for Bash. I'm converting it to Python using the PyPI `kubernetes` package.

Is there a generic way to create resources given the YAML manifest? Otherwise, the only way I can see to do it would be to create and maintain a mapping from Kind to API method `create_namespaced_<kind>`. That seems tedious and error prone to me.

Update: I'm deploying many (10-20) resources to many (10+) GKE clusters.

Comment: Have you had a look at Helm yet? https://docs.helm.sh/chart_template_guide/#the-chart-template-developer-s-guide

Comment: I have, but does Helm help me deploy to many clusters? Because if not, I'm basically in the same boat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update in the year 2020, for anyone still interested in this (since the docs for the python library is mostly empty).

At the end of 2018 [this](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/pull/655) pull request has been merged,
so it's now possible to do:

```py
from kubernetes import client, config
from kubernetes import utils

config.load_kube_config()
api = client.ApiClient()

file_path = ... # A path to a deployment file
namespace = 'default'

utils.create_from_yaml(api, file_path, namespace=namespace)
```

---

EDIT: from a request in a comment, a snippet for skipping the python error if the deployment already exists

```py
from kubernetes import client, config
from kubernetes import utils

config.load_kube_config()
api = client.ApiClient()


def skip_if_already_exists(e):
    import json
    # found in https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/utils/create_from_yaml.py#L165
    info = json.loads(e.api_exceptions[0].body)
    if info.get('reason').lower() == 'alreadyexists':
        pass
    else
        raise e


file_path = ... # A path to a deployment file
namespace = 'default'

try:
    utils.create_from_yaml(api, file_path, namespace=namespace)
except utils.FailToCreateError as e:
    skip_if_already_exists(e)
```

Comment: The function fails when resources already exist. With `kubectl apply`, it either updates the resource or skips it entirely. Is there a way to do that with the python client?

Comment: @BenDavis I've updated the answer to skip if already exists. Not sure how to update the resource instead.

Comment: I don't have the code in question at hand to test, but looks like it'd work to me :)

Answer (score 3):

I have written a following piece of code to achieve the functionality of creating k8s resources from its json/yaml file:

```
def create_from_yaml(yaml_file):
    """

    :param yaml_file:
    :return:
    """

    yaml_object = yaml.loads(common.load_file(yaml_file))
    group, _, version = yaml_object["apiVersion"].partition("/")
    if version == "":
        version = group
        group = "core"

    group = "".join(group.split(".k8s.io,1"))
    func_to_call = "{0}{1}Api".format(group.capitalize(), version.capitalize())

    k8s_api = getattr(client, func_to_call)()

    kind = yaml_object["kind"]
    kind = re.sub('(.)([A-Z][a-z]+)', r'\1_\2', kind)
    kind = re.sub('([a-z0-9])([A-Z])', r'\1_\2', kind).lower()

    if "namespace" in yaml_object["metadata"]:
        namespace = yaml_object["metadata"]["namespace"]
    else:
        namespace = "default"

    try:
        if hasattr(k8s_api, "create_namespaced_{0}".format(kind)):
            resp = getattr(k8s_api, "create_namespaced_{0}".format(kind))(
                body=yaml_object, namespace=namespace)
        else:
            resp = getattr(k8s_api, "create_{0}".format(kind))(
                body=yaml_object)
    except Exception as e:
        raise e

    print("{0} created. status='{1}'".format(kind, str(resp.status)))

    return k8s_api
```

In above function, If you provide any object yaml/json file, it will automatically pick up the API type and object type and create the object like statefulset, deployment, service etc.

PS: The above code doesn't handler multiple kubernetes resources in one file, so you should have only one object per yaml file.

Answer (score 1):

I see what you are looking for. This is possible with other k8s clients available in other languages. [Here](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/2f3e6de212f848774775bac6108b2f4d57c41f2b/kubernetes-examples/src/main/java/io/fabric8/openshift/examples/LoadExample.java#L48) is an example in java. Unfortunately the python client library does not support that functionality yet. I opened a new feature request requesting the same and you can either choose to track it or contribute yourself :). [Here](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/client-python/issues/349) is the link for the issue on GitHub.

The other way to still do what you are trying to do is to use java/golang client and put your code in a docker container.